# Eclipse Errors after Android SDK change

Tags: android, eclipse

I was having a problem upgrading my Android SDK so i did a clean re-install of the SDK in a new location.  When I have updated my build path in eclipse, but im getting the following error when i open eclipse to the  workspace:

Parsing Data for Google Inc.:Google APIs:7 failed
java.lang.NullPointerException

can someone help

Solved

I was also getting workspace open and saving errors.  In the end i created a new workspace and imported the projects and that fixed it.. what a nightmare..

Comment: @MrEngineer13 as erik wrote, recreate the workspace

Answer (score 0):

You need to open up Eclipse > Preferences.  Then go into the Android top-level node.  You can set your new `SDK Location:` there.  That should fix your issue, provided you installed the right SDK levels that your projects are depending on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have libs in your project? if so, then create "`libs`" folder in your project, move all your libraries to that folder and refresh build pathes

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, here's what I did.

1. Go to Window -> Preferences and then Android. Check to make sure your SDK location is set to C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
2. If your new SDK location doesn't have all SDKs you previously installed, use the SDK manager to reinstall them
3. Exit eclipse and then manually navigate to your workspace and remove any projects you recently added
4. Open eclipse and Fix Project Properties if necessary

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have various origins and can almost certainly be resolved by creating a new Eclipse workspace. You'll lose all you preferences and will need to reinstall any add-ons.

In my case the root of the problem was my JDK version. Eclipse had evidently located my JDK 7 installation and had set it to default. Simply changing the preference back to JDK 6 and restarting Eclipse resolved it.