# Multiple problems with Eclipse and Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Errors after Android SDK change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854986/eclipse-errors-after-android-sdk-change)

For some reason when I tried opening Eclipse today I got multiple problems that have never occurred before including:

- Android SDK Content Loader: parseSdkContent failed
  java.lang.NullPointerException
- Initializing Java tooling: An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
  java.lang.NullPointerException
- Loading data for Android 2.3.3: Parsing Data for android-10 failed
  java.lang.NullPointerException

As far as I know the problems started occurring without any action from my side, after I've first seen those problems I tried updating the SDK Tools and ADT, but the update didn't affect the problem.

I should note that the OS I use is Ubuntu 12.04 beta.

Help would be appreciated :)